# Embedding 3 bytes custom data in IPv4 header and then filter by iptables

Tags: iptables, openvpn, ipv4, tun, headers

In my modified OpenVPN server process, as an intermediate node, I'd need to embed my custom 3 bytes data in the header of every IP packet and then in the same machine (after going through `tun`) filter those packets by those custom 3 bytes.

Where's the best place in IPv4 header to put my 3 bytes? And how to retrieve it using iptables? Please note that I won't need those 3 bytes anymore after being processed by iptables.

Comment: _Every_ IP packet? What's the point of changing the packet, then, if you match _all_? You can use the [iptables mark](https://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Adv-Routing-HOWTO/lartc.netfilter.html) option (if you don't **have** to change the packet itself), for example. Or try out [libnetfilter_queue](https://netfilter.org/projects/libnetfilter_queue/index.html)

Comment: @Lenniey I rephrased the question. In server side OpenVPN process I need to tag every IP packets with 3 bytes data and using iptables retrieve the tag and do an appropriate action based on this tag.

Comment: I still don't get why you can't just filter for `source-interface tun`, if you embed the bytes in every OpenVPN packet. Maybe this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)? To filter for specific "bytes" you could use the [u32 module](https://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/netfilter-extensions-HOWTO-3.html#ss3.21), maybe?

Comment: @Lenniey Those "bytes" are not same for all packets, so I need to drop the packets tagged with some of them, something like a `switch case` statement.

Comment: @Lenniey Thanks for the u32 module, definitely it helps. But where in the IP packet should I put those 3 bytes?

Comment: Sorry, can't help you there. I still believe you don't have to change the packets' header/payload/options/whatever and you can accomplish your task differently, e.g. by marking or using some OpenVPN options or something. Modifying IP packets always sounds a bit...fishy

Comment: What is the purpose of modifying the IP packets?

Comment: @MichaelHampton In my forked OpenVPN, when I received a packet from a client, I need to drop/accept the packet based on the packet info (IP, port or higher level insights) and the client info (username, access control list), so I'm going to embed all these things inside the packet (3 bytes) and then write it on the `tun` interface. At the other end of `tun` I'd need iptables to drop/accept those packets based on those 3 bytes. Please note that those 3 bytes are not same for all packets, they may hold all combinations of 24 bits strings.